# Svelte how to import

Tags: google-api, svelte, rollup

I am working on my first svelte project and are trying to use `google-api-wrapper` with the only change being that i import: `import Google from "google-api-wrapper";`

Then, the troubles started. First was a missing `@rollup/plugin-json`, which i added.

This resulted:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: fs is not defined
(!) Missing shims for Node.js built-ins
Creating a browser bundle that depends on "querystring", "stream", "url", "assert", "https", "util", "events", "os", "path" and "buffer". You might need to include https://github.com/snowpackjs/rollup-plugin-polyfill-node
LiveReload enabled
(!) Missing global variable names
Use output.globals to specify browser global variable names corresponding to external modules
fs (guessing 'fs')
child_process (guessing 'child_process_1')
querystring (guessing 'querystring')
stream (guessing 'stream')
url (guessing 'url')
net (guessing 'net')
tls (guessing 'tls$1')
assert (guessing 'assert')
https (guessing 'https')
util (guessing 'util$1')
events (guessing 'require$$1')
os (guessing 'os')
path (guessing 'path')
crypto (guessing 'crypto$4')
buffer (guessing 'buffer')
```

and i also get this error, rather than rendering my site:`Uncaught ReferenceError: fs is not defined`

Comment: `fs` is a node specific function to read files, I suspect this library is not meant to be used in web applications.

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example]  we cant help you fix your code without seeing your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is basically not possible to use the library `google-api-wrapper` with svelte since it is a [NodeJS wrapper of the Google Drive and Sheets APIs](https://github.com/svamja/google-api-wrapper) hence the dependency of `fs` (a NodeJS library for local file IO).

I would recommend using the [Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference) or [Sheets](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest) API directly. If you want to make parsing a bit easier you can use a library like [`papaparse`](https://github.com/mholt/PapaParse).